# SQL Server Query is not working

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table exec_info which has the following columns: `exec_name, exec_regID, exec_contact, approved_by, updated_by_user_id`.

[Note: `approved_by` and `updated_by_user_id` both have `exec_regID`]

I want a query to fetch all records as well as the exec_name against approved_by (if any exist) and exec_name against updated_by_user_id (if any exist) from the table.
I have tried this one but it doesn't work for me.

```
SELECT e.exec_name, 
   e.exec_regid, 
   e.exec_contact, 
   e.approved_by, 
   a.exec_name AS ApprovedUser, 
   e.updated_by_user_id, 
   i.exec_name AS UpdatedUser 
FROM exec_info AS e, 
   exec_info AS a, 
   exec_info AS i 
WHERE  e.approved_by = a.exec_regid 
   AND e.updated_by_user_id = i.exec_regid
```

For example i have some data. Now all i want to show the same data as it is only difference is that the `approved_by` and `updated_by_user_id`'s replace by there names

```
exec_name              exec_regID    exec_contact   approved_by    updated_by_user_id 
Ali Khan              FA13-BSE-001    4534543       FA13-BSE-001       FA13-BSE-001
Tahir Khan            FA12-BSE-005    3564564       FA13-BSE-001
Hassan Abdullah       SP13-BEE-020    23423234      FA12-BSE-005
Abdul Rehman          FA15-BCC-033    34564566      FA13-BSE-001       FA13-BSE-001
```

[Image of the sample Data Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42OjU.jpg)

Comment: First, which version of sql-server are you using? You can include the tag for that. Second: please don't use [Old Style Joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: You do not get any data from table tblrole. Why "tblrole as r" in your sql? And why you make exec_info as e, as i? Cannot get what you want. Do you want all data which  exec_name != approved_by && exec_name != updated_by_user_id?

Comment: And how `tblrole` table is linked with others?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @NickyvV i am using sql server 2012. and i feel these joins are much easier to understand than the inner join that's why i use these.

Comment: @melson.jao i am sorry i was trying to join with tbrole also but It has no concern with the question. I also remove it from my question. Second: i am explaining you the scenario. When super admin update the record of the employee from the same table then his exec_regID is stored in the updated_user_id. Similarly when admin Approved the employee his exec_regID stores in the approved_by column. I want to show their names against there exec_regID as well as the record of the employee. Hope you understand.

Comment: @RjSunny have you tried my answer? Can there be more then 1 row for same `exec_regid`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it doesn't show any records.

Comment: @gofr1 yeah i tried your answer but it doesn't show any record. I explained the scenario in a upper comment. Please go thorough it. Hope it will help you to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use proper JOIN syntax, I add sample data to show that it must work well if *approved_by and updated_by_user_id both have exec_regID*:

```
;WITH exec_info AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('Rana','FA13-BSE001','03126006114',NULL,'FA13-BSE001'),
('Tahir','SP14-BCS-197','234','FA13-BSE001','1'),
('Hassan','SP14-BEE-76','','SP14-BCS-197','FA13-BSE001'),
('Abdul','SP15-BSE-002','033331212122','SP14-BCS-197',NULL)
) as t(exec_name, exec_regID, exec_contact, approved_by, updated_by_user_id)
)


SELECT e.exec_name, 
       e.exec_regid, 
       e.exec_contact, 
       e.approved_by, 
       a.exec_name AS ApprovedUser, 
       e.updated_by_user_id, 
       i.exec_name AS UpdatedUser 
FROM exec_info AS e
LEFT JOIN exec_info a
    ON e.approved_by = a.exec_regid
LEFT JOIN exec_info i 
    ON e.updated_by_user_id = i.exec_regid
```

Output:

```
exec_name   exec_regid      exec_contact    approved_by     ApprovedUser    updated_by_user_id  UpdatedUser
Rana        FA13-BSE001     03126006114     NULL            NULL            FA13-BSE001         Rana
Tahir       SP14-BCS-197    234             FA13-BSE001     Rana            1                   NULL
Hassan      SP14-BEE-76                     SP14-BCS-197    Tahir           FA13-BSE001         Rana
Abdul       SP15-BSE-002    033331212122    SP14-BCS-197    Tahir           NULL                NULL
```

Comment: Then there is no connection of `approved_by` and `updated_by_user_id` columns with `exec_regid`.

Comment: I add a sample of data, to show that query must work. Please add sample of data.

Comment: these three are the columns of same table exec_info. Where `approved_by` and `updated_by_user_id` have exec_`regID` for tracking purpose. To know who updated the record and who approved the employee.

Comment: Give some data sample and what output you need to get from this sample

Comment: i added a screen shot of table with data in my question above. Please review that.

Comment: Can you post table data as code? Screenshots are not welcome in that kind of questions

Comment: what if record of any employee never updated then this query will no show the record of that employee. For example we have values like this. Then?

`('Name1',1,'',1,2),
('Name2',2,'',2,0),
('Name3',3,'',1,2),
('Name4',4,'',2,0),
('Name5',5,'',1,0)`

Comment: Changed my answer to LEFT JOINs, check it. I guess JaydipJ answer was valid for your case.

Comment: i also added sample data in my question

Answer (score 0):

USE Outer Apply

```
SELECT e.exec_name, 
       e.exec_regid, 
       e.exec_contact, 
       e.approved_by, 
       ApprovedUserTable.ApprovedUser, 
       e.updated_by_user_id, 
       UpdatedUserTable.UpdatedUser 
FROM exec_info AS e
OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT a.exec_name AS ApprovedUser
         FROM exec_info AS a
         WHERE e.approved_by = a.exec_regid 
)ApprovedUserTable
OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT i.exec_name AS UpdatedUser 
         FROM exec_info AS i
         WHERE e.updated_by_user_id = i.exec_regid  
)UpdatedUserTable
```